# Разное поведение компиляторов для вызова функций

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, шаблоны-с++

Почему в таком контексте сначала вызывается вторая функция, а потом первая для `gcc`, а для `vc++` оба раза - вторая?

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void foo(T) {
    std::cout << "First foo\n";
}

struct A {
};

template<typename T>
void test(T t) {
    foo(t);
    foo(A());
}

void foo(A) {
    std::cout << "Second foo\n";
}

int main() {
    test(A{});
}
```

Вот выполнение для `gcc` - https://rextester.com/SUT20651, а вот для `vc++` - https://rextester.com/JWPC50675.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Краткий ответ: ["двухфазный поиск имен"](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Gn11DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA300&lpg=PA300&dq=c%2B%2B%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=W9FIJZNRVq&sig=2BTJ8H34KPpWJlhI32K3y4akrA4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5goXjv-reAhUC1ywKHcp6BtMQ6AEwBHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=c%2B%2B%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&f=false) в VC++ реализован не был.

Поскольку в строке `foo(A());` тип аргумента функции не зависит от аргументов шаблона, поиск подходящей foo должен быть произведен до того, как была объявлена `void foo(A)`. С дугой стороны, в строке `foo(t);` аргумент функции зависит от параметров шаблона, поэтому поиск функции должен быть произведен в точке материализации шаблона (т.е. в строке `test(A{});`), где `void foo(A)` уже объявлена.

Авторы VC позволили себе отступить от буквы стандарта и поиск имен всегда проводили в точке материализации шаблона. Начиная с версии [Visual Studio 2017 “15.3”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/09/11/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/), они, кажется, исправились, но я это не проверял.

Comment: В VC++ 2017 15.8.9 реализовано - выводит вторую, потом первую.